# Optimize DB requests in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have a page view in Django set up as follows:

```
    blog = get_object_or_404(Blog, subdomain=extracted.subdomain)
    all_posts = Post.objects.filter(
        blog=blog, publish=True).order_by('-published_date')
    nav = all_posts.filter(is_page=True)
    posts = all_posts.filter(is_page=False)
```

This causes the DB to be accessed 3 times. I'm trying to optimize this to only access the DB once. The following snippet reduces the number of calls to 2, but I'm sure there is a better way than this that I don't know about.

```
blog = get_object_or_404(Blog, subdomain=extracted.subdomain)
all_posts = Post.objects.filter(
    blog=blog, publish=True).order_by('-published_date')
nav = []
posts = []
for post in all_posts:
    if post.is_page:
        nav.append(post)
    else:
        posts.append(post)
```

As far as I understand, `prefetch_related` and `select_related` work inversely and I'm unsure how to implement them in this context.

My models are set up as follows:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ...

class Post(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(
        Blog,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='post')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ...
```

Thanks in advance!

*Edit:*

And for some reason this executes 3 DB requests

```
blog = get_object_or_404(Blog.objects.prefetch_related('post_set'), subdomain=extracted.subdomain)

posts = blog.post_set.filter(publish=True).order_by('-published_date')
```

Comment: You're likely optimizing the wrong thing. Why do you need two lists? You can just iterate the one queryset and inspect the property `is_page` when rendering. Only on the first iteration will the queryset be evaluated.

Comment: Yeah, I can do that on the template, which works fine without doing an extra request. I still can't seem to get the blog info and post info in the same call

Answer (score 1):

Some things:

- Separating them into two querysets or lists is a bad idea. Use the template to inspect is_page and only render it in the nav section or posts section.
- Optimizing queries like this is not where you gain the big chunks of performance. You want to get rid of queries that happen *when iterating the queryset* (so in the for loops) and that is what prefetch and select related are for.

That said, to get rid of the extra query:

```py
posts = Post.objects.filter(
    blog__subdomain=extracted_subdomain, publish=True
).order_by('-published_date')
if not posts:
   raise Http404('no posts for subdomain')
```

And to make sure you have access to Blog properties from Posts without querying with each iteration:

```py
posts = Post.objects.filter(
    blog__subdomain=extracted_subdomain, publish=True
).select_related('blog').order_by('-published_date')
```

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you :)